# Error Saving APEX Trigger - sObject type 'ContainerAsyncRequest' is not supported

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to create an APEX Trigger that strips a custom field of any HTML. I wrote this code in a Trailblazer sandbox and it was working fine. When I moved it over to my Dev org I now am getting an error message when saving:

Failed to create createContainerMember for containerId=1bg8X000000HkYgQAK: SELECT Id FROM ContainerAsyncRequest WHERE State ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:16 sObject type 'ContainerAsyncRequest' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Here is the APEX Trigger I am trying to write:

```
trigger removeHTML on Case (before update) {
    for (Case c : Trigger.New){
    c.MyCustom_Field__c = c.MyCustom_Field__c.stripHtmlTags();
    }
}
```

Currently I have made sure that my profile has:

- API Enabled
- View and Setup Configuration
- View All Data
- Write access to MyCustom_Field__c and Case

I have changed my Developer Console Workspace in case it had gotten corrupted.

Even when all I do is create the trigger and then try to change insert to update I can't save.

```
trigger removeHTML on Case (before *update*) {

}
```

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: Opening a case with Salesforce support wouldn't be a bad place to start.

Comment: How many workspaces do you have in dev console? You mentioned changing it but I'd recommend deleting any extras so there's only one. Likewise, you could look at querying `ApexClassMember` and `MetadataContainer` through tooling api and deleting the rows (warning: you'll lose any in progress apex work that isn't saved to the org). This is probably a good time to plug using VS Code over dev console as well.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I would love to use VS Code but I am not allowed. I did delete all other workspaces.